# es6 modules native support

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader

I understand the ES6 modules specification, the question is about its support. AFAIK, there are no browsers that implement this natively (see *Browser compatibility* [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)). Got a couple of questions about this:

- ES6 modules is an ES6 feature, obviously. When I look at [kangax compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/), I don't see such row (for ES6 modules) at all, why is that? It's a ES6 feature afterall...
- hence, the only way to use ES6 right now is to use a build tool, such as babel, browserify or any other aternative, right?
- how are the modules gonna be fetched, when they're natively supported - as async AJAX calls from the browser?

Comment: The first question is unanswerable, especially here on SO…

Comment: I would recommend using Webpack in combination with Babel. Webpack will answer second and third question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ES6 modules is an ES6 feature, obviously. When I look at kangax compatibility table, I don't see such row (for ES6 modules) at all, why is that?

There's [an issue being discussed](https://github.com/kangax/compat-table/issues/316) on kangax's github.

> the only way to use ES6 right now is to use a build tool, such as babel, browserify or any other aternative, right?

No. There is also a polyfill by Guy Bedford at http://github.com/ModuleLoader/browser-es-module-loader.

And there's already the preview release of Edge that implements it natively.

> how are the modules gonna be fetched, when they're natively supported - as async AJAX calls from the browser?

Yes but not exactly: they will be fetched when the are used for the first time, by a  call to an object (a function or a property) on the imported library.

Comment: thanks! you proved that it **is** posible to answer such question on SO :) perfect!
PS does the polyfill by Guy Bredford simulate exactly how should ES6 modules work, when they're natively supported (in terms of execution, not syntax)?

Comment: @ducin I'm not sure but I don't think it's possible. I guess it works more like ajax async. This could be ckecked with Dev Tools.

Answer (score 1):

Native modules are available in the following versions of browsers:

- Safari 10.1
- Chrome Canary 60 – behind the Experimental Web Platform
  flag in chrome:flags.
- Firefox 54 – behind the dom.moduleScripts.enabled setting in about:config.
- Edge 15 – behind
  the Experimental JavaScript Features setting in about:flags.

[source](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/)